# How many volumes are in Doros HaRishonim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

There seems to be a discrepancy in different places as to how many volumes there are in Yitzhak Isaac Halevy Rabinowitz's Doros HaRishonim:

- 6 volumes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzhak_Isaac_Halevy_Rabinowitz
- 7 volumes - https://il.bidspirit.com/ui/lotPage/source/catalog/auction/12400/lot/20674/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99?lang=he,
  https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3AYitzhak+Izaik+haLevi+Rabinowitz&s=relevancerank&text=Yitzhak+Izaik+haLevi+Rabinowitz&ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1
- 8 volumes - https://jewishusedbooks.com/product.asp?productid=5699

Which is it? And is the printing on Amazon the complete set?
https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3AYitzhak+Izaik+haLevi+Rabinowitz&s=relevancerank&text=Yitzhak+Izaik+haLevi+Rabinowitz&ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1

Comment: How many volumes a work is split up into may vary by edition

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. Do you know if the Amazon printing is the complete set?